# How to handle all error using connect-mongo in expressjs

Tags: express, session, connect-mongo

I am using below code for session management but not able to catch errors like: mongo authentication error. However, I am  using error middle ware as well.

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var app = express();

    app.use(session({
        secret: 'xxxsephirothxxx',
        name: 'express.sid',
        store: new MongoStore({
            url: MongoConnection.mongo_db,
            ttl: parseInt(process.env.SESSION_EXPIRY_TIME_IN_MS) / 1000
        }),
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    }));

//error middle ware but not catch mongo connection error
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(error);
  next();
  }
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
        console.log('Express server listening on ' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
    });
```

Please help. How to catch all error of application.

Thanks,Sonu